# Field Theory: Converting $\int_0^{x_0} d^dx$ to $\int_0^{x_0} dr$, where $r=^{\textrm{def}}\|x\|$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, integration

For my Statistical Field Theory class (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft/sft.pdf), the prof converts integrals over each element of a vector $x$ into a single integral over the magnitude of the vector $r=\|x\|_2$. For example, see the bottom of page 49 in the expression for $R$, where (after substituting the correct values of the variables) the numerator has

$$\int_0^\xi d^dx \dfrac{1}{\|x\|^{d-2}}\sim
\int_0^\xi dr \dfrac{r^{d-1}}{r^{d-2}}.
$$

To me this seems to imply something like
$\int_0^\xi d^dx \propto
\int_0^\xi dr\ r^{d-1}.$ But I'm unsure how to verify this.

Please note that $d^dx$ is his notation for integrating over each element of the vector $x$.

Comment: This isn't really a question specific to physics, but rather one about the mathematical concept of [volume integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element).

Comment: See a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3226242/prove-int-fracdd-kk2-propto-int-kd-3-dk